# polars: n_unique(), but as a window function

Tags: python, python-polars

I need a way to find out how many unique pairs of values from two columns are in a certain context.
Basically like n_unique, but as a window function.

To illustrate with a toy example:

```py
import polars as pl

dataframe = pl.DataFrame({
    'context': [1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3],
    'column1': [1, 1, 0,  1, 0, 0,  1, 0, 1],
    'column2': [1, 0, 0,  0, 1, 1,  1, 0, 1]
    # unique:   1  2  3   1  2  -   1  2  -
    # n_unique: -- 3 --   -- 2 --   -- 2 --
})
```

I would like to write:

```py
dataframe = (
    dataframe
    .with_column(
        pl.n_unique(['column1', 'column2']).over('context').alias('n_unique')
    )
)
```

to get the number of unique value pairs from column1, column2 within the window of column 'context'. But that does not work.

One attempt I made was this:

```py
(dataframe
    .with_column(
        pl.concat_list(['column1', 'column2']).alias('pair')
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.n_unique('pair').over('context')
    )
)
```

To be honest, I wasn't really expecting this to work, and indeed it doesn't:

```
PanicException: this operation is not implemented/valid for this dtype: List(Int64)
```

But then what can be done? The "Power BI way" would be to string merge columns, but isn't there a proper way?

EDIT: I found one way, but I don't like it...

```py
(dataframe
    .with_column(
        pl.when(pl.all().cumcount().over(['context', 'column1']) == 0)
          .then(pl.n_unique('column2').over(['context', 'column1']))
          .otherwise(pl.lit(0))
          .alias('n_unique')
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col('n_unique').sum().over('context')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All expressions are this functional construct `Fn(Series) -> Series`. Meaning that if you want to compute something over multiple columns, you must ensure that there are multiple columns in the input `Series`.

We can easily do this by packing them into a `Struct` data type.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'context': [1, 1, 1,  2, 2, 2,  3, 3, 3],
    'column1': [1, 1, 0,  1, 0, 0,  1, 0, 1],
    'column2': [1, 0, 0,  0, 1, 1,  1, 0, 1]
})

df.with_column(
    pl.struct(["column1", "column2"]).n_unique().over("context").alias("n_unique")
)
```

```
shape: (9, 4)
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┐
│ context ┆ column1 ┆ column2 ┆ n_unique │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---      │
│ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ i64     ┆ u32      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪══════════╡
│ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ 0       ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1       ┆ 0       ┆ 0       ┆ 3        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 1       ┆ 0       ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...     ┆ ...     ┆ ...     ┆ ...      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2       ┆ 0       ┆ 1       ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 0       ┆ 0       ┆ 2        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 3       ┆ 1       ┆ 1       ┆ 2        │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┘
```